# linux skel and default files what does . file do?

Tags: linux

when you look at /etc/skel

you see the default files. such as (.  ,   ..  ,  .bash_logout,.bash_profile
,.bashrc .gnome2 .kshrc .mozilla)

what does the . and .. file do and why this .. file is only belonging to

the root when you create the user?

Comment: You should have googled a bit. anyways dot (.) represents the current directory and double dot (..) represents the previous directory. Try `cd ..`

Answer (score 0):

The `.` and `..` entries are present in every directory, not only `/etc/skel`.  They are hard links to, in order, the current directory and the parent directory.

The parent directory doesn't necessarily belong to the root user; to see what I mean, try creating some tree directory structure in your homedir (as a normal user, not root) and navigating it.